# Get spring transaction by it's ID and check status

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, transactional

Is there any way to get current transaction id, store/pass it, and check it's status in the another part of application?

For example:

```
@Service
public class Service {
    ...
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void performAction(Action action) {
        // start action
        String transactionId = ???     // getting current transaction id
        messenger.send(transactionId); // sending transaction id to consumer
        // continue action
    } <- commit transaction
}

public class Consumer {
    ...
    public void onRecieveMessage(String transactionId) {
        TransactionStatus ts = ??? // getting transaction from pool by id
        if (ts.isCompleted()) {
            // some actions
        } else {
            // wating or Future<?> or something else...
        }
    }
}
```

(Actually, the problem is Consumer.onRecieveMessage executes earlier than action's transaction finishes, and data state is old)

Answer (score -1):

I do not know any way of getting a specific transaction by its ID (hopefully someone does).

What I would do is to implement an instance of `TransactionSynchronization` that holds a kind of value you want to track:

```
public class YourTransactionTracker extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {

    private Value value;

    public YourTransactionTracker(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        //transaction handling your 'value' has been completed with the status 'status'
        //do whatever you want here
    }

    //you can also override other methods like beforeCompletion(), flush(), etc...
    //have a look at TransactionSynchronizationAdapter
}
```

`TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` is just an implementation of `TransactionSynchronization` with empty methods.

Then you can hook a callback in the transaction with your `TransactionSynchronization` instance, that will be called in the different stages of the lifecycle of the transaction.

You can do this in Spring by using the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`:

```
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
             new YourTransactionTracker(theValueYouAreTracking);
```

Comment: Anyway, how to get transactionId in this case?

Comment: @NikolayShabak sorry, I don't know how to. I have edited my answer with an alternative solution.